# PHP array: how to find all keys in array by passing multiple values?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there is easy&elegant way to get all keys of input array by passing another array as values?

```
$haystack = array (
  11 => 'Parenting',
  48 => 'How',
  50 => 'Parenting',
  54 => 'parenting',
  57 => 'parenting',
  58 => 'style',
  59 => 'that',
  60 => 'offer',
  61 => 'kids',
  62 => 'greater',
  63 => 'freedom',
);
$needle = ['Parenting', 'offer', 'freedom'];
```

Desired output:

```
$output = array (
      11 => 'Parenting',
      50 => 'Parenting',
      54 => 'parenting',
      57 => 'parenting',
      60 => 'offer',
      63 => 'freedom'
);
```

I tried [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) as its described in PHP.net, but it returns an empty Array.

```
$output= array_keys($haystack, $needle);
```

Comment: Notice you have `parenting` and also `offers` in the desire output but none in the `$needle`

Comment: I used `similar_text` to solve your issue of non-identical string - check my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have case sensitivity problems then you can use preg_grep and implode.

I implode the needle and separate them with "or" and use regex option for case insensitive.

```
var_dump(preg_grep("/" . implode("|", $needle) . "/i", $haystack));
```

If you have "regex" characters in the needle then you must use preg_quote but since `|` is a regex character the preg_quote will "undo" it, so I have to fix that with str_replace.

```
var_dump(preg_grep("/" . str_replace("\|", "|", preg_quote(implode("|", $needle))) . "/i", $haystack));
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) is what you need.

> array_intersect() returns an array containing all the values of array1 that are present in all the arguments. Note that keys are preserved.

Do note that comparison is case sensitive.

So you can convert the array to lowercase and then do [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) on them,

```
$haystack = [
    11 => 'Parenting',
    48 => 'How',
    50 => 'Parenting',
    54 => 'parenting',
    57 => 'parenting',
    58 => 'style',
    59 => 'that',
    60 => 'offers',
    61 => 'kids',
    62 => 'greater',
    63 => 'freedom',
];

$needle = ['Parenting', 'offer', 'freedom'];

$result = array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', $haystack), array_map('strtolower', $needle));
```

Comment: Nice! The problem is, which I didnt mention, that I cant change $haystack arr case. Or I need to make another iteration to return previous letter case, which is complicated...

Answer (score 0):

You can filter array ([array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)):

```
$output = array_filter($haystack, function ($v) use ($needle) {
    return in_array($v, $needle);
});
```

Comment: What the `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` for?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a simple function that everybody will understand. To me, it's easy and elegant.

```
function getFragArray($arrayValues, $arrayKey) {
    $resu = [];
    foreach ($arrayValues as $key=>$value) {
        if(in_array($value,$arrayKey)) {
            $resu[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $resu;
}
```